# Why does Android Emulator show black screen with Android flashing on it?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have installed Eclipse Helios and Android Sdk. The problem is that when I launch an Emulator I get a black screen with android text flashing on it. I get the following errors in the Log.Can anyone please suggest a step by step solution to this problem.
Here are the errors:

```
02-27 05:59:50.070: E/logwrapper(920): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
02-27 05:59:51.130: E/cutils(932): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-27 05:59:51.130: E/installd(932): Could not create directories; exiting.
02-27 05:59:51.790: W/InterfaceController(925): Warning (dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
02-27 05:59:51.920: E/keystore(933): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
02-27 05:59:52.250: D/Vold(923): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
02-27 05:59:53.270: E/SurfaceFlinger(928): hwcomposer module not found
02-27 05:59:53.270: W/SurfaceFlinger(928): getting VSYNC period from fb HAL: 1536001
02-27 05:59:53.280: W/SurfaceFlinger(928): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
02-27 05:59:53.280: W/SurfaceFlinger(928): EGL_SLOW_CONFIG selected!
02-27 05:59:53.320: W/SurfaceFlinger(928): power module not found
02-27 05:59:54.910: E/SurfaceFlinger(928): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-27 05:59:54.940: D/libEGL(993): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
02-27 05:59:55.860: E/cutils(1010): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-27 05:59:55.860: E/installd(1010): Could not create directories; exiting.
02-27 05:59:56.030: E/keystore(1011): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
02-27 05:59:57.230: E/AudioFlinger(931): int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
02-27 06:00:05.810: E/cutils(1060): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-27 06:00:05.810: E/installd(1060): Could not create directories; exiting.
02-27 06:00:06.040: E/keystore(1061): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
02-27 06:00:06.840: E/memtrack(929): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-27 06:00:06.840: E/android.os.Debug(929): failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-27 06:00:10.220: I/installd(1085): installd firing up
02-27 06:00:10.220: E/cutils(1085): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-27 06:00:10.220: E/installd(1085): Could not create directories; exiting.
 02-27 06:00:10.570: E/keystore(1086): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
02-27 06:00:15.720: E/cutils(1109): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-27 06:00:15.720: E/installd(1109): Could not create directories; exiting.
02-27 06:00:16.230: E/keystore(1110): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
02-27 06:00:29.190: E/EmojiFactory_jni(929): Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
```

Comment: You should wait for the emulator to load completely if you are talking about the initial text that flashes. It will take approx 10 minutes to get loaded. Then run your application.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and creating a new emulator?

Comment: I have tried deleting and creating a new emulator. But it doesn't help.

Comment: When that black screen comes with Android text flashing on it, it means that the emulator is loading. Let it load.

Comment: It means your android emaulator is loading(it takes around 8-10mins to load) .Let it load after that your app. will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "flashing android text" means the emulator is booting. That can take a while depending on how fast your machine is.

Sometimes it just gets stuck and you have to deleed it and start over,  but it sounds you have already tried that.

When booting the emulator from Eclipse, look at the Console tab, not the log tab. Console may show error messages. The Log tab only shows logcat, which are messages from Android itself

When you create a new emulator it warns you about assigning it too much RAM if you try anything above 768M the emulator may not start according to the error message at the bottom of the virtual device setup.
Do try with 512M of RAM and see if it starts.

Answer (score 8):

While creating emulator check the option "Use Host GPU" at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

I've found this same issue.  The same error messages display over and over again, in a loop.  It occurs when I upgrade the emulator to API version 19.  (I waited overnight, but the emulator never started up.)

BUT, if I run the emulator with API version 17, it started up fine after about five minutes.  (By the way, I allocated 512 megs both times.)